# PubNub over GCM?

Tags: android, .net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

Hi I want to implement GCM with bi-directional communication for my android application. I have searched for bi-directional GCM .net tutorial and have not found anything.

And I found PubNub. They said For bi-directional communication that must be reliable and message length upto 32kb etc.

Is that reliable and better over GCM?

Comment: If you are looking for push notification for Android device only, GCM will be a great choice. Many popular apps in the Google Play use GCM for their push notification. GCM is the best integrated push notification for Android, also it is free and reliable. GCM message length is about 4kb. So depends on what OS you are supporting, and how large is your message, also your budget.

Comment: To get more info about bi-directional communication on GCM, please refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html). It has examples in Java and Python.

Comment: @ztan Yes is an android app. But Now the GCM depends on Google play service where Amazon fire phone and xiaomi wont support this. So I thought of go with pubnub.

Comment: @koh I already referred this. Please understand the objective of my question.

Answer (score 0):

PubNub can be used for your bi-directional communication via our pub/sub service and you can add GCM on top of that (integrated with PubNub via our Mobile Push Gateway service - includes APNS and MPNS) so that the user will get push notification when app is in the background. Or you can even use a background service to stay connected in realtime with Pubnub.

See the following links for further details:

- http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call#latest
- http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/380/can-my-android-app-receive-messages-while-inactive#latest

Comment: To implement the bi directional channel whether the Pubnub also uses GCM. I have to implement GCM and also pubnub or else only pubnub. How it would be?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the details of your use case and questions but the link I posted should answer this question. And there are two links at the end of that article that should be helpful.
http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call#latest

Please provide a bit more detail if this doesn't help.

Comment: @Craig, Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759028/how-to-receive-missed-messages-on-resuming-connection-lost-in-pubnub.